# Where should I place the java properties file under netbeans

Tags: netbeans, properties

In my netbeans IDE I am creating one project.That project(Web Application) needs properties file.Since my application is having several packages.And all packages need to read this properties file in their code.So where should I place this java properties file.If I place the file out side of the packages that is under sourcepackages seperately,I am getting FilenotFound Exception.So where should I place it.
And one more doubt is if I want to change any content in the file in future where should I change the contents since it is present in  Projects folder and under Files->build->classes folder also.From where should I modify it.From where the changes will be effected.
Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Put your file under `/src/resources/`, then use it like below:

```
ResourceBundle props = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.config");
```

Answer (score 3):

You may put this in any package. The point ist to read with

```
MyClass.getResourceAsStream("my.properties");
```

Read further [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

You always change in the project src folder. The build folder is only for building your app.

If you want to change the properties file on a deployed system you may put the properties into the WEB-INF folder and then access with ServletContext#getRealPath().

Answer (score 0):

I put the .properties file in the same folder as the src and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I'm working on Windows and here's my solution...

It actually doesn't matter much where you put the .properties file--but assuming you created the file in NetBeans and let it save to its default location, you can simply call the data with the full directory attached.

Just for reference, here's what I did:

```
SimpleDataSource sds = new SimpleDataSource("src\\simpledatasource\\mystuff.properties");
```

Notice you'll need to escape the backslash, so use two of them.